# Getting error in bash script of partitioning disk

Tags: bash, shell

I keep getting this error when i execute the bash script (**./partion.sh: line 11: $'n\np\n1\n\nw\n': command not found
**):

```
./partion.sh: line 11: $'n\np\n1\n\nw\n': command not found
Checking that no-one is using this disk right now ... OK

Disk /dev/sdd: 3 GiB, 3221225472 bytes, 6291456 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0ca4ca9d

Old situation:

>>>
New situation:
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

hdd="/dev/sdd"

for i in $hdd;do
echo 
"n
p
1

w
"|sfdisk $i;done
```

I am still a newbie so really appreciate all the help i can get=)

Comment: What are those commands `n` `p` `1` `w` ? What exactly are you trying to  achieve there? Are you trying to print those letters ?

Comment: [This article](http://xmodulo.com/how-to-run-fdisk-in-non-interactive-batch-mode.html) shows how to use `sfdisk` in a non-interactive manner. It might be a better way for you to get this done.

Comment: @VikasTiwari  Commands for partioning a disk

Comment: But those are sfdisk commands, not shell commands. And trying to use echo to send commands into another program from bash is usually not a good way to control an interactive program..

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be:

```
#!/bin/bash

hdd="/dev/sdd"

for i in $hdd;do
echo "n
p
1

w
"|sfdisk $i;done
```

Multi-line echo should start on the same line. Else, next line is treated as a command on its own.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra newline between the command `echo` and the string that you are telling the shell to echo, which is what is causing your error message.

But you are also sending interactive commands to `sfdisk`, which is not an interactive tool. Your code appears to be based on the top of [this article](http://xmodulo.com/how-to-run-fdisk-in-non-interactive-batch-mode.html), which @GregTarsa linked in his comment, but that is sending those commands to *fdisk*, not *sfdisk*. (You are also missing another newline between the `l` and `w` fdisk commands.)

The *sfdisk* program is designed to take a text description of the desired partitioning layout and apply it to a disk. It doesn't expect single-letter commands on input; it expects its input to look like this:

```
# partition table of /dev/sda
unit: sectors

/dev/sda1 : start=     2048, size=   497664, Id=83, bootable
/dev/sda2 : start=   501758, size=1953021954, Id= 5
/dev/sda3 : start=        0, size=        0, Id= 0
/dev/sda4 : start=        0, size=        0, Id= 0
/dev/sda5 : start=   501760, size=1953021952, Id=8e
```

Which is less generic than the `fdisk` commands, since it requires actual block numbers, but much easier to use (and for someone reading your script to understand), since you're not trying to remote-control an interactive program by `echo`ing commands to it.

If you *are* going to remote-control an interactive program from the shell, I recommend looking into [`expect`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html) instead of doing blind `echo`s.

Also, in general, if you are trying to print multiline data, `echo` is probably not the way to go. With lines this short, I would reach for `printf`:

```
printf '%s\n' n p l "" "" w | fdisk "$i"
```

But the more generally useful tool is the here-document:

```
fdisk "$i" <<EOF
n
p
l


w
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

A newline terminates a command.  If you want to pass a multiline argument to `echo`, you need to move your quote.  For example:

```
for i in $hdd; do
    echo "n
p
1

w
" | sfdisk $i
done
```

It would probably look better to write:

```
for i in $hdd; do printf 'n\np\n1\n\nw\n' | sfdisk $i; done
```

A third option is to use a heredoc:

```
for i in $hdd; do
sfdisk $i << EOF
n
p
1

w
EOF
done
```

Comment: Now i'm getting this error:

    **Old situation:

    line 1: unsupported command
    >>>
    New situation:
    Leaving.**

Comment: None of them is working, still getting the same error as mentioned xD
Do appreciate your help, though=D